# How to create folders by reading excel names in a sheet (using python)?

Tags: python, excel, merge, directory, path

I want to read an excel file and create folders after what its written inside the sheet.
I would like  to get the first 2 columns, merge them and then, create folders named after them. well, I am new and tried looking all over the forums...

this is my code:

```
arquivo = xlrd.open_workbook('C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\Engetran\\Ceriluz\\01-Projeto Executivo\\00 - Documentos\\EGTR-M-P03 - Documentos.xls')
linha = arquivo.sheet_by_index(0)

lista_valores1 = linha.col_values(0)
lista_valores2 = linha.col_values(1)
lista_valores = f"{lista_valores1} {lista_valores2}c"

os.mkdir('C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\Nova pasta (5)\\Projeto Executivo')
root_path = 'C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\Nova pasta (5)\\Projeto Executivo'
folders = [ lista_valores ]
for folder in folders:`
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(root_path,folder))`
```

I get an error:

```
filenotfounderror winerror 3 the system cannot find the path specified
```

I would be thankful for any response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to xlrd-documentation, the "col_values" method returns a slice of cells in the given column. As you didn't pass in any other parameters, it will return your whole column. After this you try to put those (probably huge) slices into an format-string. What's the content of that string? It could contain invalid charachters or it may be to long for a path.

Try and see what os.path.join returns in the end and see, if it is even possible to create a directory with such a name.

Feel free to share your further insights for more help, if you get stuck again.

Comment: well, it reads everything, i dont know how to select only what's written, only the first 2 columns with everything inside (now i got this one):
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: "C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\Nova pasta (5)\\ Projeto Executivo\\['', '', '', '', 'LT 69 kV IJUI 2 - CERILUZ 3', '', 'RELAÇÃO DE DOCUMENTOS', '', 'Nº', '', 1.0, '', 2.0, '', 3.0] ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'DESCRIÇÃO', '', 'Planta Geral do Traçado', '', 'Memorial Técnico Descritivo', '', 'Perfil Planialtimétrico']c"

Comment: See "lista_valores1" as a list (it's actually a slice). You can index it just like other lists, like lista_valores1[0] will return the first cell of the first column of your excel sheet

Comment: hum, worked somewhat haha
created 1 folder with all thats written inside the sheet: " ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'DESCRIÇÃO', '', 'Planta Geral do Traçado', '', 'Memorial Técnico Descritivo', '', 'Perfil Planialtimétrico']c"
without the numbers, but i need them.. exemple of what i need: "1 - Planta Geral Traçado" --> folder created; "2 - Memorial Tecnico Descritivo" second folder creater; etc...

Comment: im stuck again haha